# handling launching options and local notifications correctly

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

I'm not absolotly sure about how to deal with the different states of handling a local notification (or a push for that matter).

these are the different scenarios as far as I understand them (correct me if I'm wrong):

a. app was in the foreground

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{}
```

is getting called and: application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive

b. app was in the background

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{}
```

is getting called and: application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive

c. the app was terminated so:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{}
```

is getting called first and afterwords:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{}
```

is getting called where application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive (since it became active some time after didFinishLanching...

In each of these 3 scenarios I should act differently:

a. if the app was in the foreground, i would like to display an alert that shows the notificaiton body, and push some view controllers on the stack if the user dismisses the alert with a proceed button.

b. if the app was in the background, and the user pressed on the alert then i would like to automatically push the view controllers to the stack, since the user's pressing on the alert indicates he wants to follow it's meaning.

c. same scenarios as b. the user pressed on the alert and expects to see the relevant views.

My Question is how/where should I push the relevant views to the navigationViewController and how to display the alert when receiving the notification in the foreground?

The problem is that scenario c contains scenario a. this means, after didFinishlaunching got called (never mind if I handled the notification there or not) then didRecieveLocalNotification is getting called (as if I got the notification while in the foreground), but in this case i would not want to display an alert..

Am I Wrong about the assumptions to begin with?

Comment: For scenario C, `didReceiveLocalNotification` is not called, only `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called. Since these are app delegate methods, they can receive the events at any time, and you can do anything you want from there. Maybe ask more specific questions, one at a time.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, thx. I actually asked a very specific question, and followed it with wether I had my assumptions wrong to begin with. And I did, as you said the didReceiveLocalNotification method doesn't get called in scenario C, which simplifies everything. Go ahead and convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scenario C, `didReceiveLocalNotification` is not called, only `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called.

Since these are app delegate methods, they can receive the events at any time (regardless of which view controller is active), and you can do anything you want from there.

For example, you can show a `UIAlertView` right from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (before the default `return YES;`) and set the app delegate as the `UIAlertView`'s delegate so you can handle the dismissal of the alert.

Also, be aware that if the app is in the foreground when receiving the local notification, the user doesn't receive an alert. It's up to you to alert the user if needed.